# Is it right to have cyclic dispatch in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have 2 slices in my redux store - chats and messages.

On sending a message without specifying the chat, it should create a chat for it and then send the message in it. Thing is, I don't want to have the logic of sending a message inside the chat slice, or vice-versa.
So in the `sendMessage` function I check if the chatId is specified, and if not - I dispatch a `createChat` action instead, that will dispatch a new `createMessage` with the chatId.

Something like this:

```
// messagesSlice
const sendMessage = (message, chatId?) => dispatch => {
    if(!chatId) {
        dispatch(chatsSlice.actions.createChat(message));
        return;
    }
    messageService.sendMessage(message, chatId);
}
```

```
// chatsSlice
const createChat = (message) => async dispatch => {
    const chat = await chatService.createChat();
    dispatch(messageSlice.actions.sendMessage(message, chat.id));
}
```

I also thought about passing a `createCallbackAction` to the `createChat`:

```
const createChat = (message, createCallbackAction) => async dispatch => {
    const chat = await chatService.createChat();
    dispatch(createCallbackAction(chat.id));
}
```

So `chatStore` will not know about `messageStore`.

But it feels like both of these are anti patterns. Is there a correct way to do it?

Comment: IMO the message service should not be responsible for creating a chat room at all.

Comment: Maybe you could have a container which knows about the chat and message services and does the logic that involves both of the services

Comment: Interesting, but then the container will handle the "state" of waiting for the chat room to be created, right? I mean, it'll dispatch a "createChat" and somehow will wait for it to be created so it can dispatch the "create message". Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, if the chat room has to be created first, it will wait for it

Comment: You can listen for sendMessage actions in your chat slice  with the extraReducers property: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#extrareducers

Comment: If you want full separation of concerns like @Muhammed is talking about, then basically in the component that is calling sendMessage you would also conditionally call createChat or call chatMustExist(id) or something.  But if sendMessage depends on the chatId then it’s already not really separate?  Idk.  But the extraReducers approach is easy to implement.

Comment: Looking at the complete code I'm just confused -- it looks like your mesagesSlice doesn't actually update its state at all in response to the sendMessage action?

Comment: Yea the code is just for demonstraiting the problem.. Of course it will push the new message into a `messages` state array.Anyway, in the container approach, I can't really find a good way to "wait" for the chat room to be created. Because the conditional creation of the chat room will be just dispaching an action, not something I can (or should) wait for inside a component.